# Vertices with edges not drawn with plotly in a network graph

Tags: python, plotly

I have been following the instruction from here to draw a network graph:
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/empet/07ea33b2e4e0b84193bd

I have been replicating the networkx example as I have had troubles to compile and install igraph on my Ubuntu VM.
Here is an example of result I would obtain: [plotly network graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owasw.png)

For some reason, the nodes that have edges are not visible.

I hope that someone has some idea about where the problem might originate. I have been reusing the same layout parameters as in the example I was trying to reproduce.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I found out the root of the problem. There was a mismatch between the identifiers of the nodes and the edges.

I was still using the labels of the nodes to add the edges instead of the node identifiers (integers used for positioning). As a consequence, plotly did not know where to connect the edges.